# Question regarding convergence of metric space

Tags: real-analysis

If $X$ is a metric space and if $S_n$ and $T_n$ are two sequences such that $\lim S_{n}=S$ and $\lim T_{n}=T$ then prove that $\lim S_{n}T_{n}= ST$. Well it can be easily proved for $\mathbb R$.  But can't prove it for arbitary metric spaces.

Another question is given.. what happens if X=$R^k$??

Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: It's not even clear what you mean $S_nT_n$. The real numbers are a field so you can multiply together its elements. Arbitrary metric spaces don't have any product structure on them, so you have to consider that point first.

Comment: Ohkk. There is another question what happens if X=$R^k$

Comment: What what do you mean by $SnT_n$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$?

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, there is no product structure on arbitrary metric spaces, but for certain spaces there is.

In particular, $\mathbb R^k$ has the *dot product* defined by $(a_1,\dots,a_k)\cdot(b_1,\dots,b_k) = \sum a_ib_i$. If $S_n\to S$ and $T_n\to T$ in $\mathbb R^k$, you can prove that $S_n\cdot T_n\to S\cdot T$; the key idea being to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $|x\cdot y| \le |x|\,|y|$.

To see the inequality in action, we have
\begin{align*}
|S_n\cdot T_n - S\cdot T| &\le |S_n\cdot T_n - S\cdot T_n| + |S\cdot T_n - S\cdot T| \\
&= |(S_n- S)\cdot T_n| + |S\cdot (T_n -  T)| \\
&\le |S_n - S|\,|T_n| + |S|\,|T_n-T|.
\end{align*}

It shouldn't be a problem to finish the proof from this point.

Comment: The problem I am having in $R^k$ is that if we know $lim S_{n}=S$. Then we can't say for all $\epsilon$ there exist a $N$ such that $|S_{n}-S| < \epsilon$ for all $n\geq N$.

Comment: @user426700 On the contrary, that's exactly what we can say. You should review what it means to say $S_n\to S$.

Comment: Forgive me, but i disagree. According to me im $R^2$ $|x-y|$ makes no sense. U can't say  the value of $|(1,2)--(2,3)|$. That's why we have to use different metric formulas such as euclidean metric. Or others.  Is there anything wrong in my statement?

Comment: @user426700 Apologies; I thought it was understood that the bracketing symbols $|\,|$ without qualification meant the standard Euclidean norm. Of course convergence in $\mathbb R^k$ is understood to mean *with the Euclidean metric* if it's not qualified. It's a standard abuse of notation.

Comment: Ooh. OK.  Thanks